# Ubuntu - Clearing Orphaned Inode and Can't Switch to Virtual Terminal

Tags: command-line, mount

When I reboot my desktop, it gives a bunch of lines that look like:

/dev/FOO: Clearing orphaned inode BAR(uid=0, gid=0, size = FOOBAR)

Eventually it gets to a line like:

/dev/FOO: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks

and hangs.

Looking at previous posts, it seems that the usual answer is to use ctrl-alt-F3 (or similar) to open a virtual terminal. However, that doesn't do anything on my computer. Any advice on what to do?

Comment: Does the system not finish booting? Where does it stop?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help clarify your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS. Thanks

Comment: To Nmath: Sorry for being clear. By "hang" I mean it doesn't put any more output after that line, and it also doesn't respond to any of the input I tried.

To richbl: I'm sorry, I can't get on the computer to check the version number. It was installed about 3 months ago.